# Junit Test Cases Generator

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I have an existing Java EE Application Code, for which i need to write JUnit Test Cases.

Is there a free easy to use tool which will generate basic Junit Test Cases for me for the code base (hundreds of classes across packages) - i will update these test cases post their generation ?

I can't find any good tool in this regard. Any suggestions in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is an easy way to do that.

and JTest is a commercial tool

if you are using spring roo it will easy to have junit test cases